# Preventing parent firing jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to allow folding and unfolding of a nested list by either clicking the `li` or the `input type=[checkbox]` adjacent to the `li`. But checking the checkbox causes firing of the container `li` causing the parent `li` to fold.

Easier explained by [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mfbx9da4/QwNYh/1/)

I solved it by setting a global

```
window.checkbox_checked = true
```

show in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mfbx9da4/cXct4/3/) but I'de rather not use a global. Is there a cleaner way of doing this? I tried using `event.stopImmediatePropagation()` and `event.stopPropagation()` but neither worked for me?

Thanks

#### Update

As pointed out by Felix King, my problem was wrapping my `li` in a `div`, which disabled `event.stopPropagation()` [solution](http://jsfiddle.net/QwNYh/5/)

Comment: *"I tried using `event.stopImmediatePropagation()` and `event.stopPropagation()` but neither worked for me?"* Maybe you are not using it *correctly*? Please post the corresponding code.

Comment: NVM, I just had a look at your HTML. It's completely invalid. A `div` element cannot be the child of a `ul` element. The text and the `input` element have to be children of the `li` element which has to be a child of the `ul` element. Then `stopPropagation` should work as expected.

Comment: @FelixKling yeah true, but then i lose the formatting! ideally the input would be on the left.

Comment: Easily done: http://jsfiddle.net/QwNYh/5/.

Answer (score 1):

Just check the `node name` inside the `click handler` if it is an `UL` then just skip that particular `click event`.

```
event.target.nodeName
```

Code:

```
$('li.expandable').on('click', function (e) {

if(e.target.nodeName !== "INPUT")
{
    //Code goes here.
}
});
```

### <s>[DEMONSTRATION](http://jsfiddle.net/cXct4/4/)</s>

Comment: This doesn't work when I select any of the `input` elements. Which is the OP's problem: *"But checking the checkbox causes firing of the container li causing the parent li to fold. "*

Comment: Yeah sorry dude doesn't work for me either

Comment: @david_adler :) wait i'm looking on it.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy `!= 'INPUT'` works but stops the checkbox being checked

Comment: @david_adler Yeah it works, I checked it now. Did you find any other workaround.?

Comment: yeah see felix king's fiddle in the comments above